# MySQL 5.1 High Cpu usage on CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, centos

I am running MySQL 5.1 on a CentOS 6 server with 16G ram. I got also apache on it.

MySQL is constantly using too much cpu.

```
top - 17:40:36 up 112 days, 12:13,  1 user,  load average: 1.24, 1.72, 1.82
Tasks: 222 total,   1 running, 221 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.3%us, 11.6%sy,  0.4%ni, 72.9%id,  2.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16329040k total, 12946136k used,  3382904k free,   587252k buffers
Swap:  1051832k total,  1050988k used,      844k free,  4986272k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
25368 mysql     20   0 8854m 5.3g 5064 S 295.4 33.9  11912:37 mysqld                                                                                                                                 
 1757 apache    20   0  982m  80m  28m S  2.0  0.5   0:03.04 httpd                                                                                                                                   
 2494 apache    20   0  878m  68m  27m S  2.0  0.4   0:00.92 httpd
```

my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=127.0.0.1

key_buffer        = 800M
max_allowed_packet    = 32M
thread_stack        = 256K
thread_cache        = 8
thread_cache_size    = 20
thread_concurrency = 4
max_connections        = 510
table_cache            = 9000
interactive_timeout = 80
tmp_table_size = 540M
max_heap_table_size = 540M
max_connect_errors = 150
wait_timeout = 20
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1024K
connect_timeout = 10
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit   = 40M
query_cache_size        = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M

join_buffer_size = 14M
sort_buffer_size = 14M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` is returning me on average 2-5 queries.

[Here is the output of SHOW VARIABLES; command.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2fd8adf13fe3fd4aa423)

We got MyISAM and InnoDB tables in this system.

Thank you for any suggestions.

## EDIT 1

[Here is the vmstat output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b646b984aac82b83f74).

## EDIT 2

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` output is available below in the comments.

Comment: Your CPU is 72.9%idle . How many CPUs your server has?

Comment: @Antonis He may have ~8-12 cores. High CPU usage is not necessarily a bad thing- it means that your load is not IO-bound. The problem is what you are using those cycles for. Check your query plans and latency though the slow log to see if that is reasonable.

Comment: @jynus if he has 8-12 cores and iowait is 2.8% then probably one thread might have more than 20% iowait which is IO-bound. I agree on the query plans usually high CPU usage come from poor queries.

Comment: It's a quad core machine with HT support but not enabled.

Comment: Your tables are InnoDB or MyISAM or both? I notice that your swap space is occupied. Could you please run a vmstat 1 for a minute and share the si/so?

Comment: @Antonis We got both types of tables. I've added a link to the vmstat output.

Comment: Please also share the output of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

Comment: Here is the show global status output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c23fae6df542c653dac5

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the slowest query in the system.  Quite likely, fixing it (adding an index, reformulating the SELECT, etc) is the best solution.  You mentioned SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST -- That is likely to show the naughty queries; let's see them, plus the associated SHOW CREATE TABLEs.

query_cache_size        = 128M -- too big; no more than 50M.  A big value slows down the system with pruning.

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M and key_buffer        = 800M -- What ENGINE are you using?  Neither of these values is likely to be 'good'.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory for further advice.  A poorly-sized cache could lead to extra I/O, which would be seen as slow queries.

table_cache            = 9000 -- Yikes!  How many tables do you have?  (Thousands of tables is an OS problem.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an inactive legacy website hosted on this server. It was a target of heavy spamming. 
I solved this issue by putting some tables in read-only mode.